# Setting attributes on active record join tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a standard has_many through association in active record with an added "quantity" attribute on the join table.

When using this syntax to add an association, how do I set a value for the quantity attribute in the join table.

```
order.products << Product.find(params[:product_id])
```

The only way I have been able to accomplish this is by creating the "join object" directly like this:

```
order.product_orders.create(:product => Product.find(params[:product_id], :quantity => 5)
```

The second approach kind of bugs me because I am addressing the join directly.

Is there an alternate/better way to approach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your better approach is 1. You have to separete product and order item.

Comment: I like the clean syntax of the first approach but I am unable to set the attribute on the join model with that method.